# SQL and PHP aggregating statistics, performance issue using COUNT hundreds of times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a PHP page doing 1000 SQL queries. It is giving statistics on events that have occured for a list of users. The page takes a bit long to load (6 seconds now with indexes tweaked). I want to know if there is another/better way to do this than 1000 individual queries. And is there a faster way, particularly as the data grows.

The results of those 1000 SQL queries are placed into PHP arrays and eventually populate cells of an html table, like so:

```
         Installs    Called    Early Install   Event4   Event5    (... 9
George     5           6          3              5        29      different event
Greg       9           7          1              8        23      types, up to
David      4           1          2              4        0       maybe 15
Dan        15          17         4              20       10      eventually)
...        ...         ...        ...            ...      ...
...        ...         ...        ...            ...      ...
Totals     351         312        82             289      1220

(... there are up to ~50 users, maybe 100 total in the next two years)
```

Some columns are actually percentages that are calculated on the fly in PHP from the data like (event4/installs)*100.

The table is always over a given data range like:
Choose date range: `Dates Jan 15, 2013 - March 31, 2013`.

`event` table's fields: `id, event_type, user_id, event_date`

The data itself is stored as a table made up of events that occur on certain dates. The most frequent type of SQL statement the PHP page is firing are count queries that look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM events
WHERE userid = 10
    AND `event_date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-15'
    AND event_type = 'Install';

SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM events
WHERE userid = 10
    AND `event_date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-15'
    AND event_type = 'Called';

SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM events
WHERE userid = 10
    AND `event_date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-15'
    AND event_type = 'Early Install';

/* and so on for each event type and user id */
```

These counts() populate the cells of the html table. It does these counts() in a php loop that goes over each user (representing each row in the html output table) and within each row it goes over each event type (columns) and does a `COUNT` for each one. ~50 users, ~10 event types, you get around ~1000 individual SQL requests on one page.

1. Is there a reasonable way to combine all these individual SQL `COUNT` operations or to do this all faster or more correctly without all of the individual `COUNT` calls coming from PHP? Maybe a stored procedure... does that make sense? and if so how to approach (bunch of count queries or cursor or what)? and how to construct/return back rows of calculated counts data from a stored procedure?

I guess I'm wanting to know, is this the "right way"®?

I'm not asking for an answer to the whole question necessarily just answers to a part that you might be able to answer, or how you'd approach.

Also (#2) How might this stuff be cached? Cached by bringing all the COUNT values to PHP and then writing out those values from PHP to a mysql table with a row for each user and each date range, or cached somewhere/somehow else?

Comment: We would need to see a sample data set (preferrably on SQL Fiddle)

Comment: wow you wrote out 1000 queries instead of just using `group by`? Or am I way off here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping comes to mind.

```
SELECT userid, event_type, COUNT(id) AS cnt
FROM events
WHERE `event_date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-15'
GROUP BY userid, event_type
ORDER BY userid, event_type
```

This would return an array where each row roughly has the structure of:

```
array(
    userid=>10,
    event_type=>'Installs',
    cnt=>5
);
```

And you can iterate over that to build your table.

```
//iterate over the data first constructing a new array for below
$newData = array();
$headers = array();

foreach($data as $row){
    //save the data in a multi dimensional array under the userid
    if(!isset($newData[$row['userid']])){
        $newData[$row['userid']]=array();
    }
    $newData[$row['userid']][$row['event_type']] = $row['cnt'];
    $headers[$row['event_type']]=1;
}
//get the headers
$headers = array_keys($headers);

//display the data for debugging
echo '<pre>'.print_r($newData,1).'</pre>';

echo "<table colspan=0 cellspacing=0 border=1>\n";
//add "user id" to the headers
array_unshift($headers, "User ID");
//echo the headers
echo "\t<thead>\n\t\t<th>".implode("</th>\n\t\t<th>", $headers)."</th>\n\t</thead>\n";
//remove the user id column from headers
array_shift($headers);

echo "\t<tbody>\n";
//now loop over the new data and display.
foreach($newData as $userID=>$row){
    //start row
    echo "\t\t<tr>\n";
    //user id
    echo "\t\t\t<td>{$userID}</td>\n";
    //loop over the headers. there should be corresponding keys for each header
    foreach($header as $key){
        //get the count if the key exists and '-' if not.
        $cnt = isset($row[$key])?$row[$key]:'-';
        echo "\t\t\t<td>{$cnt}</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "\t</tbody>\n</table>\n";
```

Comment: Grouping would be a solution and I think that'll shave some time however the table you've constructed wouldn't be how the table looks now. In your table the events would be in rows next to the user name rather than as columns of events with 1 row for each user. Maybe fill a multidimensional array with the results?

Comment: you are correct, I'll fix the table. I was running on pretty much no sleep.

Comment: @user2116469 that should do it. You would need to first iterate over the data and build a better structured array. then you can loop over the array and output the data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  event_type,
  COUNT(id)
FROM 
  events
WHERE 
  `event_date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-15'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

EDIT: This is only a partial answer. I'm not really an authority on caching :) Sorry can't help that part.